# connected fibers of a partial desingularization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I had been told this once, but cannot deduce it from the standard references. Is it correct?

I'm working over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f : X \to Y$ be a birational proper morphism where $X$ is normal with rational singularities. Assume that $f$ has connected fibers. Then $f_* \mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}_Y$.

If it is not correct is it possible to repair it in a reasonable way by placing additional constraints on the fibers?

Comment: I don't think this can be correct without some additional assumption on $Y$.  For example suppose $Y$ is a plane cubic curve with a cusp: $x^3-y^2=0$. Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be normalisation. If those two sheaves were the same, they would have the same spaces of global sections, but that would give an isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: very good. thank you!